# iOS AVAudioPlayer can't REplay when asked to play again at the end (works before and after end of file but not a THIS specific moment)

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

Sorry for the weird title but AVAudioPlayer acts a bit weird when it comes to playing a sound again, right before the sound that it's playing ends.

I can play an mp3 file when the player is not playing, when the player finished playing and when the player is playing.
I **cannot** play an mp3 when the song that is currently playing is about to end. This is my code, I documented the important bits.

```
-(void) play:(int)p{
    if([players[p] isPlaying]){
        NSLog(@"is playing"); 
        [players[p] setCurrentTime:0.025f]; //when it's playing, set it to the start of the 
                                            //file so it starts playing again. Usually works

        if(![players[p] isPlaying]){ 
            NSLog(@"is not playing"); //although I just told the player to play again
                                      //it sometimes returns that it in fact does NOT play
                                      //so it's playing in the first if condition but
                                      //not playing in the second if condition
            [players[p] prepareToPlay];
             [players[p] play];       //from here I try to resurrect the player numerous times
                                      //but everything fails, I have to call the function again to make it work

            [players[p] setCurrentTime:0.025f];
             if([players[p] isPlaying]){
                 NSLog(@"playing");     //never gets called; although I tell it to play so many times
                                        //it just won't do
             }else {
                 NSLog(@"NOTplaying");
     [players[p] play];
             }


        } else {
            NSLog(@"is still playing"); 
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"not playing at all");
        [players[p] play]; } //if not playing, play. Always works
}
```

I think this might have something to do with how the AVAudioPlayer releases the file or that it's playing but is not playing anyumore in the millisecond after that. (playing during the first if condition but stopped right after that).

The window in which this occurs can easily be reproduced with with a 5sec audio file. Just wait till it's about to end and then click "play" and the method gets executed but nothing's playing. The method works in every other case (not playing and playing but not going to finish playing).